# simultaneous implicit matrix equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, implicit, equation

I have two matrix equations that I need to solve simultaneously. I'm using MATLAB. They're of the form

XAY=C1;

YAX=C2;

where all the variables are square matrices (2x2 currently), A,C1,C2 are all known and I'm solving for X and Y. A is diagonal, X and Y are orthogonal. I have no idea how to do this (numerically or otherwise). Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the right place to ask maths questions!

Anyway, I don't think there is a solution as you have the equations
`XAY = C1`
`YAX = C2`
`Y.t Y = I`
`X.t X = I`
(where .t is the transpose, I the identity). The latter two equations are the orthogonality of X and Y.

Written in components: the first two correspond to n^2 equations each, the second two to less than 2*n^2 but still more than 2*n (as there are some degenerate component equations). So you have 2*n^2 unknowns but more than 2*n^2 equations, i.e. a over-determined system.  But maybe there is something I'm missing.

If you drop the orthogonality requirement there should usually be a unique solution. However, it is a system of non-linear equations which you can try to solve with matlab's fsolve function (in the Optimization Toolbox).